# Swift 3: How to retry Firebase upload on failure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm initializing some data in Firebase that I will use to track a user's activity. I need to make sure this data is written to Firebase so I'm wondering what the best practice is for ensuring a critical upload was successful?

```
static func createUserActivityCounts(uid: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) {
            let databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
            let userCounts: [String: Any] = ["posts": 0,
                                             "comments": 0,
                                             "likes": 0]
            databaseReference.child("userActivity").child(uid).child("counts").setValue(userCounts) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to resolve this issue is to check if the value exists whenever you attempt to query a critical upload. If the value isn't there then you initialize it. Here is the function I wrote to handle this.

```
private func getUserActivityCounts() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
    userRef.child("userActivity").child(uid).child("counts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
            if !snap.exists() {
                // create user counts
                if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    DatabaseFunctions.createUserActivityCounts(uid: uid)
                }
            }
            if let counts = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
                if let numberOfLikes = counts["likes"] as? Int, let commentCount = counts["comments"] as? Int, let postCount = counts["posts"] as? Int {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.headerRef.postCount.text = String(postCount)
                        self.headerRef.commentCount.text = String(commentCount)
                        self.headerRef.likeCount.text = String(numberOfLikes)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                    self.numberOfUserPosts = postCount
                    self.commentCount = commentCount
                    self.likeCount = numberOfLikes
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```